# Text dictionary like transformation in Google DLP

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I would like the data to be masked, but it was possible to understand how many people studied at UNIVERSITY_1.

What de-identification transformation can I use to accomplish such information\text masking?

**Input:**

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "university": "University of Pennsylvania"
        },
        {
            "formattedName": "Mike Miller",
            "university": "Harvard University"
        },
        {
            "formattedName": "Elon Musk",
            "university": "University of Pennsylvania"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "university": "UNIVERSITY_1"
        },
        {
            "formattedName": "Mike Miller",
            "university": "UNIVERSITY_2"
        },
        {
            "formattedName": "Elon Musk",
            "university": "UNIVERSITY_1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom infotype with a single dictionary item (1 per college) and do a replace with infotype transform - how many schools are in your data set?

Answer (score 0):

You could use crypto hashing: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#cryptohashconfig